# magento error message only displays after 2nd page refresh

Tags: magento, notifications

I have an observer watching the event sales_quote_item_set_product. In it, i am checking some conditions to make sure the item is still available. If it is not, i run this code:

```
Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->removeItem($item->getId())->save();
Mage::getSingleton('message/session')->addError($item->getName() . ' is no longer available.');
```

The problem I'm having is if an item becomes unavailable and a guest is on a product view page, the cart says the item is in the cart, but the total for the cart is updated to reflect the product being removed. Also the error message is not displayed. If you go to another page or refresh the product view page the error message will display and the number of items in the cart will be correct.

So my thought is i need to run this code earlier in the execution cycle, but i have no idea what event i should be observing, or if i shouldn't be using an observer at all. I tried using sales_quote_load_after, but that caused a recursion error somehow. Can anyone tell me when/where i should run this code?

Another wild thought is could it be because i'm using database sessions instead of the file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the error was being added after the messages block was rendered. I fixed it by adding a redirect to the cart page after the error was added.

```
$request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
if($request->getModuleName() != 'checkout' && $request->getControllerName() != 'cart' && $request->getActionName() != 'index') {
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getModel('core/url')->getUrl('checkout/cart/index'))
        ->sendResponse();
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention it, but this sounds like you're running code during an AJAX request.  When you say

```
Mage::getSingleton('message/session')->addError($item->getName() . ' is no longer available.');
```

You're adding an error to Magento's session object.  Every time a Magento page renders, it checks the session object for errors, and displays them all.  This allows multiple developers to add multiple errors to the session, redirect Magento back to the original form.

This doesn't work during an ajax request, because (typically) the rendering process is skipped in lieu of a JSON object or simple, errorless HTML chunk being rendered (leaving the errors in the session).

Knowing what the full request cycle looks like (what's ajax, what's not) would help someone come up with a more concrete answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help Alan, I've gotten a lot of useful info from your blog and love Commerce Bug! Unfortunately the event wasn't firing in an ajax request. It was happening when the cart summary was being generated. Which loaded after the messages were rendered. My solution was to redirect the user so they could fix the error. I'm not 100% happy with the fix, but i couldn't find an event that was firing early enough and had the sales quote data in it.

Comment: @JasonNeumann Ah, yeah — if the action you're listening for happens after the messages block has rendered, there's not much you can do.  It might be possible to gin up something that renders some additional JS to add to the page that adds additional errors, but that's probably more work that you're looking for.  Also, Re: finding events, don't forget that commerce bug two has an event and observers tab -- useful for tracking these things down http://commercebugdemo.pulsestorm.net/